# spring data mongo find method has no return

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I use spring scheduler+spring data mongo.

Now I meet a problem.The find() method on MongoTemple will block.

program blocks on

```
List<HistoricalDataModal> historicalList = mongoOperation.find(symbolQuery, HistoricalDataModal.class,"EibHistoricalDataInf");
```

**UPDATE COMPLETE CODE:**

**I replace find with findOne,always block**
Java Code

```
  public void realtime() {
          try {
                Query query = new Query();
                List<ContractDetails> contractDetailList = mongoOperation.find(query, ContractDetails.class,"EibContractInf");
                if(contractDetailList == null || contractDetailList.size() == 0) {
                    logger.error("contractdetail error");
                    return;
                }

                for(int index = 0;index < contractDetailList.size();index++) {
                    Query symbolQuery = new Query();
                    symbolQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("symbol").is(contractDetailList.get(index).contract().symbol()));
                    FundamentalModal fundamentalDetail = mongoOperation.findOne(symbolQuery, FundamentalModal.class,"EibFundamentalInf");
                    if(fundamentalDetail == null)
                    {
                        logger.error("fundamentalDetail error");
                        continue;
                    }
                    logger.debug("debug1");

                    logger.debug("debug");

                    /*List<*/HistoricalDataModal/*>*/ historicalList = mongoOperation.findOne(symbolQuery, HistoricalDataModal.class,"EibHistoricalDataInf");
                    logger.debug("debug");
                    if(historicalList == null /*|| historicalList.size() == 0*/) {
                        logger.error("historicalList error");
                        continue;
                    }
                    logger.debug("debug");

                }

          }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
      }
```

log output:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARtH3.png)

**If I replace HistoricalDataModal with FundamentalModal,the program don't block.So It's HistoricalDataModal problem.But I don't know why.**

Comment: What happens if you try mongoOperation.findOne? It gives you a result or it still blocks?

Comment: @DanielC. Not findOne,findOne don't block.find method will block

Comment: Assuming that the database is too big, then one possible solution is to use a Pageable in order to limit the amount of data that you get from Mongo DB.  Something like this Pageable myPagable = new PageRequest(0, 10);  then set it to the query like this: symbolQuery.with(myPagable);  It will return 10 documents

Comment: @DanielC.I use mongo-shell to fetch the same collection, only 4 records returned.So I think it's not because of the big database.

Comment: One additional question, why is there a continue statement inside if? are you looping for some reason?  Also could you try System.out.println("debug") instead of logger.debug in order to see the output?

Comment: @DanielC.Yes.I post entire code.First findOne method is success.The second find method block

Comment: What happens if you try this: replace the find to findOne like this: HistoricalDataModal historicalObject = mongoOperation.findOne(symbolQuery, HistoricalDataModal.class,"EibHistoricalDataInf");  and comment  the rest of the code before the loop ends.  Another question, could you provider the entire log output, it is because I dont see the "debug1" or "debug" messages.  Please also verify  if the "symbol" attribute is pesent on the EibHistoricalDataInf collection

Comment: @DanielC.I have tries replace find with findOne,always block,I have update code and log output, log output is a picture.Thank you

Comment: ok I see it.  could you share the `HistoricalDataModal` class and the list of documents in `EibHistoricalDataInf` collection in order to compare both definitions.

Comment: i think that the problem comes from whith the definition of `com.ib.client.Bar` according to the log that class is also analyzed. is this class part of your mongo document? also could you share that class definition?

Comment: @DanielC.I have update code on the answer.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing one example of how to validate if you `Bar` class is mapped correctly to your Mongo Document.

For example, it is a Collection of `historicalDataModal` objects from mongo shell:

```
> db.getCollection("historicalDataModal").find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599eba80ee19f50d0ceecb07"), "_class" : "com.mongodb.demo.mongodbdemo.model.HistoricalDataModal", "symbol" : "xiix", "bar" : { "m_time" : "1234", "m_open" : 23, "m_high" : 34, "m_low" : 45, "m_close" : 56, "m_volume" : NumberLong(23), "m_count" : 2, "m_wap" : 34.5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599ebaacee19f50d56141eb7"), "_class" : "com.mongodb.demo.mongodbdemo.model.HistoricalDataModal", "symbol" : "xiix", "bar" : { "m_time" : "1234", "m_open" : 23, "m_high" : 34, "m_low" : 45, "m_close" : 56, "m_volume" : NumberLong(23), "m_count" : 2, "m_wap" : 34.5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599ebab1ee19f50d932f8c29"), "_class" : "com.mongodb.demo.mongodbdemo.model.HistoricalDataModal", "symbol" : "xiix", "bar" : { "m_time" : "1234", "m_open" : 23, "m_high" : 34, "m_low" : 45, "m_close" : 56, "m_volume" : NumberLong(23), "m_count" : 2, "m_wap" : 34.5 } }
>
```

As you can see the properties of `Bar` object starts with `m_`, for example `m_time`, `m_open`, `m_high`.  Actually the `Bar` class has the properties with that prefix.  But the constructor has not the same prefix, actually the `Bar` constructor has `time`, `open`, `high` without the `m_` prefix.

In order to see an alternative for this kind of behavior try with the following `Bar`class, you will see that the constructor has the same prefix as the members of the `Bar` class

**Option 1: Bar class without constructor**

```
public class Bar {

    private String m_time;
    private double m_open;
    private double m_high;
    private double m_low;
    private double m_close;
    private long m_volume;
    private int m_count;
    private double m_wap;


    public String time() {
        return m_time;
    }

    public double open() {
        return m_open;
    }

    public double high() {
        return m_high;
    }

    public double low() {
        return m_low;
    }

    public double close() {
        return m_close;
    }

    public long volume() {
        return m_volume;
    }

    public int count() {
        return m_count;
    }

    public double wap() {
        return m_wap;
    }

}
```

**Option 2 Bar class with constructor with the same prefix name**

```
public class Bar {

    private String m_time;
    private double m_open;
    private double m_high;
    private double m_low;
    private double m_close;
    private long m_volume;
    private int m_count;
    private double m_wap;

    public Bar(String m_time, double m_open, double m_high, double m_low, double m_close, long m_volume, int m_count, double m_wap) {
        this.m_time = m_time;
        this.m_open = m_open;
        this.m_high = m_high;
        this.m_low = m_low;
        this.m_close = m_close;
        this.m_volume = m_volume;
        this.m_count = m_count;
        this.m_wap = m_wap;
    }

    public String time() {
        return m_time;
    }

    public double open() {
        return m_open;
    }

    public double high() {
        return m_high;
    }

    public double low() {
        return m_low;
    }

    public double close() {
        return m_close;
    }

    public long volume() {
        return m_volume;
    }

    public int count() {
        return m_count;
    }

    public double wap() {
        return m_wap;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Bar.java

```
package com.ib.client;

public class Bar {

    private String m_time;
    private double m_open;
    private double m_high;
    private double m_low;
    private double m_close;
    private long m_volume;
    private int m_count;
    private double m_wap;

    public Bar(String time, double open, double high, double low, double close, long volume, int count, double wap) {
        this.m_time = time;
        this.m_open = open;
        this.m_high = high;
        this.m_low = low;
        this.m_close = close;
        this.m_volume = volume;
        this.m_count = count;
        this.m_wap = wap;
    }

    public String time() {
        return m_time;
    }

    public double open() {
        return m_open;
    }

    public double high() {
        return m_high;
    }

    public double low() {
        return m_low;
    }

    public double close() {
        return m_close;
    }

    public long volume() {
        return m_volume;
    }

    public int count() {
        return m_count;
    }

    public double wap() {
        return m_wap;
    }

}
```

HistoricalDataModal.java

```
package pro.elijah.batch.modal;

import com.ib.client.Bar;

public class HistoricalDataModal {

    private String symbol;
    private Bar bar;
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HistoricalDataModal [symbol=" + symbol + ", bar=" + bar + "]";
    }



}
```